# Show a message from ViewBag set in a controller on an Exception and Stay in the same View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**What I have**

A single view 'AddEdit.cshtml' that is used to both Edit and also Delete a Student entity.

Edit ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int Id)
{
    // code to get the Student object create a VM and call the view passing the VM

    ViewBag.Mode = "Edit";
    return View("AddEdit", studentVm);
}
```

Delete button in the same view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete Student", "Delete", new { id = Model.StudentId }, new { role = "button", @class = "btn btn-danger",id="deleteStudent" })
```

In case of an exception when deleting I want to inform the user by showing a message in a alert so I added this code:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id) 
{
    var student = _publisherManager.GetStudentById(id);
    try
    {
        _studentManager.DeleteStudent(student);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        // Logging code

        ViewBag.DeleteStudentError = "This student is currently acitve and cannot be deleted.";

        // Code to get the VM same as in the Edit method and call the view with it
        return View("AddEdit", studentVm);

    }
    // All well go to the Index view
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**Not able to do**

1. Show the message from ViewBag
2. The Url after the click says

> Student/Delete/14

Instead of

> Student/Edit?Id=14

Any clues?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We can't really see what's happening in your view, because we can't see your view. Please post (at least some relevant code from) your `AddEdit.cshtml` view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your url will be always `Student/Delete/14`. If you want to change this to `Edit` you must redirect your action.

That is,

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id) 
{
    var student = _publisherManager.GetStudentById(id);
    try
    {
        _studentManager.DeleteStudent(student);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        // Logging code
        // You can't use ViewBag because we will redirect to another action.
        //ViewBag.DeleteStudentError = "This student is currently acitve and cannot be deleted.";

        // You can use TempData to pass parameter across actions
        TempData["DeleteStudentError"] = "This student is currently acitve and cannot be deleted.";


        // Code to get the VM same as in the Edit method and call the view with it
        return RedirectToAction("Action_Name_Of_Edit",student);

    }
    // All well go to the Index view
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And you can use this `TempData["DeleteStudentError"]` in your `AddEdit.cshtml`.

Your view should be,

```
<span class="alert"> @(TempData["DeleteStudentError"]??string.Empty) <span>
```

Comment: That helped Abhilash. One more thing how do I use TemData in an alert, currently I am showing the message in a Span?

Comment: You can display message as same as using ViewBag. I can add this to my answer right now.

Comment: @Codehelp, Yes, Updated